# Parse Weather Forecast Data (from the NDFD) in c#

Tags: c#, xml, weather-api

I am using > http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl webservice to get the weather detials by calling GmlTimeSeries webmethod. Now I just want to read temparature, weather icon link details from the xml. The xml has huge data. Can anybody give an idea to fetch the required data from the xml?

[NDFD HOme Page](http://www.weather.gov/xml/#frequency)

The XML looks almost like below : [Full XML File is Here](http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLclient.php?whichClient=GmlLatLonList&lat=&lon=&listLatLon=&lat1=&lon1=&lat2=&lon2=&resolutionSub=&listLat1=&listLon1=&listLat2=&listLon2=&resolutionList=&endPoint1Lat=&endPoint1Lon=&endPoint2Lat=&endPoint2Lon=&listEndPoint1Lat=&listEndPoint1Lon=&listEndPoint2Lat=&listEndPoint2Lon=&zipCodeList=&listZipCodeList=&centerPointLat=&centerPointLon=&distanceLat=&distanceLon=&resolutionSquare=&listCenterPointLat=&listCenterPointLon=&listDistanceLat=&listDistanceLon=&listResolutionSquare=&citiesLevel=&listCitiesLevel=&sector=&gmlListLatLon=38.99,-77.02%2039.70,-104.80%2047.6,-122.30&featureType=Forecast_Gml2Point&requestedTime=&startTime=2000-01-01T00:00:00&endTime=2012-01-01T00:00:00&compType=Between&propertyName=wx,temp,icons&product=time-series&begin=2004-01-01T00:00:00&end=2015-06-07T00:00:00&maxt=maxt&Submit=Submit)

I want to fetch Temparature from below xml data:

```
 <gml:featureMember>
          <app:Forecast_Gml2Point>
             <gml:position>
                <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326">
                   <gml:coordinates>-87.8859170,41.7450495</gml:coordinates>
                </gml:Point>
             </gml:position>
             <app:validTime>2011-06-07T12:00:00</app:validTime>
             <app:temperature>77.0</app:temperature>
          </app:Forecast_Gml2Point>
       </gml:featureMember>

       <gml:featureMember>
          <app:Forecast_Gml2Point>
             <gml:position>
                <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326">
                   <gml:coordinates>-87.8859170,41.7450495</gml:coordinates>
                </gml:Point>
             </gml:position>
             <app:validTime>2011-06-07T15:00:00</app:validTime>
             <app:temperature>90.0</app:temperature>
          </app:Forecast_Gml2Point>
       </gml:featureMember>
```

And weather phrase from below:

```
 <gml:featureMember>
      <app:Forecast_Gml2Point>
         <gml:position>
            <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326">
               <gml:coordinates>-87.8859170,41.7450495</gml:coordinates>
            </gml:Point>
         </gml:position>
         <app:validTime>2011-06-08T03:00:00</app:validTime>
         <app:weatherPhrase>Mostly Clear</app:weatherPhrase>
      </app:Forecast_Gml2Point>
   </gml:featureMember>

   <gml:featureMember>
      <app:Forecast_Gml2Point>
         <gml:position>
            <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326">
               <gml:coordinates>-87.8859170,41.7450495</gml:coordinates>
            </gml:Point>
         </gml:position>
         <app:validTime>2011-06-08T06:00:00</app:validTime>
         <app:weatherPhrase>Mostly Clear</app:weatherPhrase>
      </app:Forecast_Gml2Point>
   </gml:featureMember>
```

The above is a piece of xml file. Like this I have large data for 7 days weather details. I need to read for the temp and weather condition from above xml.

[Full XML File is Here](http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLclient.php?whichClient=GmlLatLonList&lat=&lon=&listLatLon=&lat1=&lon1=&lat2=&lon2=&resolutionSub=&listLat1=&listLon1=&listLat2=&listLon2=&resolutionList=&endPoint1Lat=&endPoint1Lon=&endPoint2Lat=&endPoint2Lon=&listEndPoint1Lat=&listEndPoint1Lon=&listEndPoint2Lat=&listEndPoint2Lon=&zipCodeList=&listZipCodeList=&centerPointLat=&centerPointLon=&distanceLat=&distanceLon=&resolutionSquare=&listCenterPointLat=&listCenterPointLon=&listDistanceLat=&listDistanceLon=&listResolutionSquare=&citiesLevel=&listCitiesLevel=&sector=&gmlListLatLon=38.99,-77.02%2039.70,-104.80%2047.6,-122.30&featureType=Forecast_Gml2Point&requestedTime=&startTime=2000-01-01T00:00:00&endTime=2012-01-01T00:00:00&compType=Between&propertyName=wx,temp,icons&product=time-series&begin=2004-01-01T00:00:00&end=2015-06-07T00:00:00&maxt=maxt&Submit=Submit)

Comment: I tried to parse the xml using XDocument.Parse() method. but unable to read `<app:temperature>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972798/linq-to-xml-how-to-get-an-element-that-has-in-its-name)

Edit:
you need to use namespace, for example:

```
XNamespace app = "http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/OGC_services";
var result = from i in doc.Descendants(app+"Forecast_Gml2Point")
                  select new 
                  {
                      temperature = i.Element(app + "temperature"), 
                      icon = i.Element(app+"weatherIcon")
                  };
```

Edit 2:
if you need to get Element with other namespace, here is another example:

```
XNamespace gml ="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
i.Element(gml+"coordinates" )
```

Comment: I tried the way explained in the given link but unable to read it like that

Comment: **` var getTemp = from i in XDocument.Parse(strResult).Descendants("Forecast_Gml2Point") select i.Element("temperature"); `**... I am getting 'Enumeration yielded no results' error

Comment: xml example you posted is full? Iam missing root part. If you post all your xml(strResult content), or show where you get it from i could at least try to test.

Comment: @Reniuz : I edited my Question to provide the Full XML file. Please get it at bottom of the question.

Comment: This response is from webserivce.

Comment: I got the value for one tag. Same like I have several tags for temparature and weathericon. To get this which attribute of element() method i have to use?

Comment: I misunderstood. Do you want to mach temperature with weathericon?

Comment: Thanks for helping... I want the match with The date ,Temparature and weatherPhrase. For each date there will be 8 results in the xml response. What I need is : for Example: todays date is june 7th so the solution should give me temp and weatherphrase of today's date. I hope you have seen the Full XML I have provided in the question.

Comment: Try to use where statement like where i.Element(app+"validtime")==june 7

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if you use the "Add Web Reference" feature of Visual Studio. In this way, Visual Studio generates all the (proxy) classes for you base on the WSDL, and you can then program against the classes like how you'll do normally. In other words, there is no parsing of XML needed.

As pointed out in [this link](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dotnetwebservices/DotNetWebServices.asp):

> Visual Studio.Net Web References are proxy classes created on the client to connect to the Web Service running on the server. Inside of the IDE Web references automatically generate code and insert hidden files into your project. This is required because .Net is type safe and in order to compile code that uses the Web Service, the client has to know the method signature of each method that is called.

You might want to refer to [the above link](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dotnetwebservices/DotNetWebServices.asp) about consuming WSDL in details.

Comment: I am using the webservice in that way only. here the webmethod of the webservice gives the response in a XML format which I provided in the question.

Comment: if that's the case, i suggest you using LINQ to XML if the .Net version you are using supports it... LINQ to XML provides useful classes such as XElement that allows you to parse XML document quickly... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299195(v=VS.100).aspx...

Comment: have a look at the answer given by @Reniuz above. You will get what exactly I want